# Are there any providers for Spring cloud config and Eureka

Tags: .net, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

The company has primarily Java applications but with a new .Net app coming up. The company uses Spring Cloud Config and Spring Cloud Netflix (Eureka & Zuul), I am trying to figure out how to connect to spring cloud config (open source lib / s.c config's http api doc) to get the necessary data. And Eureka for service discovery.

I need the connection options for .Net 4.6.x and not .Net core. I ran into this: https://github.com/SteelToeOSS, but its fairly new and built for .Net core anyway.

I would personally prefer to use Consul, however, I need to evaluate these first in case we can avoid adopting a new technology.

Comment: anybody has an answer to this?

Comment: Why not using plain REST API with `.NET` http client? `Eureka` API can be found here https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations. I think you could find the same for `Spring Cloud Config`.

Comment: yeah, I was refraining from it, basically since the Java community connects through the lib, I wanted to have a third-party worry about changes, how & what to cache, failovers, retries etc.

Comment: Ok so i can't help you more. I'm not `.NET` developer

Comment: thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to give an newer answer.  Steeltoe has added a ton of features around the area you are looking.  Steeltoe has added support for .NET Framework and .NET Core now too.   If you need a .NET Framework support for Spring Clound Config and Eureka, Steeltoe can definitely help you here.